# richfaces 4+jsf and faces-config.xml that doesn't work

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I use richfaces 4. And I have session bean with property - user. I expect that my xhtml-pages don't render for requests if user is null because I have faces-config.xml with if-tag (see below). But they renders (just when I type url  myComp:8080/JSF/faces/clients.xhtml) and I see in a debuger that user property isn't checked in session bean.

faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
      <navigation-case>
       <from-outcome>clients</from-outcome>
       <if>#{userBean.isUser}</if>
       <to-view-id>/clients.xhtml</to-view-id>
      </navigation-case>
```

Do I need some VeiwHandler or something wrong with faces-config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously it'll not work because you didn't actually navigate from `/login.xhtml` to `/clients.xhtml` did you? For the navigation rule to be evaluated, you need to actually be on `login.xhtml` and then navigate by a control on that page to `clients.xhtml`.

Navigation cases cover specific navigation cases , i.e. if-then-else logic. So going straight to the outcome completely sidelines the navigation logic. That's why you're better off implementing the validation at the destination. Something like the following, based on the `<f:event name="preRenderView"/>` try the following on the `clients.xhtml`:

1. Add the following to your `clients.xhtml`. It stipulates that a method `checkValidUser`

   ```
   <f:metadata>
      <f:event  type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.checkValidUser}">
   </f:metadata>
   ```
2. In your backing bean, add the following

   ```
   @ManagedProperty("#{userBean}")
   UserBean theUserBean;    //this injects the UserBean into the destination bean. I'm assuming UserBean is a SessionScoped bean here

   public void checkValidUser(){
     if(userBean.isUser==false){
         throw new ValidationException("not a valid user");
     }
   }
   ```

Alternatively, you could just add the `@PostConstruct` annotation to `checkValidUser` and ignore (1) altogether. It'll achieve basically the same effect, `checkValidUser` will run immediately after the bean is instantiated. The *faces-config.xml* based navigation approach, IMO is implicitly flawed and optimistic, because as you can see it's too easy to bypass and break your application

Comment: @Foontik, you're welcome. Please accept the answer to confirm that my recommendation has solved the challenge. Also [see how accepting an answer works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)